# How do I provide arguments to a command run from gksudo?

Tags: command-line, gksudo, nice

I want to add a shortcut for `gnome-system-monitor` that runs with root access and has very high priority.

My command for the shortcut is:

```
gksudo -k -u root nice --20 gnome-system-monitor
```

But this gives the error:

```
gksudo: unrecognized option '--20'
```

How can I say that the `--20` is an option of `nice`, not `gksudo`?

Is this the best command for what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using:

```
gksudo -k -u root -- nice --20 gnome-system-monitor
```

The double dash (`--`) signifies the end of the parameter list for `gksudo`, so it doesn't try to interpret the `--20` as a parameter to `gksudo`.

More information about this "bare double dash" can be found [on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/45600).